# if checkbox is checked and using slideToggle

Tags: jquery, checkbox, slidetoggle

I'm using `slideToggle` to display image related forms when a checkbox is enabled and hide it if not checked.

My menu structure is as follows:

```
<ul>
<li class="menu-item">
    <p>
        <label><input type="checkbox">...</input>Upload Image?</label>
    </p>
    <div class="settings-image">...image related forms...</div>
</li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

My jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("option-checked", this.checked);            
        $(this).closest('li.menu-item').find('.settings-image').slideToggle();      
    });
});
```

This works just fine when the checkbox isn't `checked` yet on pageload.

The problem is when the checkbox **is** `checked` on pageload. Neither the `toggleClass` name and `settings-image` div shows by default.

Any help in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: What about setting the class on load. e.g.              
$('#element').on('load', function() {
    ...
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `.trigger('change');` in your change function which will trigger the change when loaded.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("option-checked", this.checked);
    $(this).closest('li.menu-item').find('.settings-image').slideToggle();
  }).trigger('change');



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <p>
      <label><input type="checkbox" checked>...</input>Upload Image?</label>
    </p>
    <div class="settings-image">...image related forms...</div>
  </li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```